# Update different session by key

Tags: php, session

Let's say I have two sessions. One has `$_SESSION['email'] = 'abc'`, the other has `$_SESSION['email'] = 'xyz'`. Both of these have `$_SESSION['show'] = 0`

While using the computer with `$_SESSION['email'] = abc`, I want to change `$_SESSION['show']` to `1` for the user with `$_SESSION['email'] = 'xyz'`.

Basically I want to update a different user's session. Is this possible?

Comment: Store data (email + show) in a MySQL database and you can just fetch the information based off an ID stored in the clients session that is unique to them.

Comment: @Matt I'm trying to avoid doing a database query on every page load.

Comment: Why exactly? You'll find that pretty much every site ever does that.